# realmdb SwiftUI relationship problem: Object is already managed by another Realm. Use create instead to copy it into this Realm

Tags: swiftui, realm

Within my project, I've got the following model hierarchy: a *table top game* can have a *list of card decks* and *each card deck* can have a *list of cards*, but *every card* could be *part of different decks*. The models would look like this:

```
class TableTopCardGame: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var cardDecks = List<CardDeck>()
}

class CardDeck: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var label: String
    @Persisted var cards = List<CardInDeck>()
    @Persisted(originProperty: "togglesPages") var tableTopCardGame: LinkingObjects< TableTopCardGame>
}

class CardInDeck: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var indexInDeck: Int
    @Persisted(originProperty: "cardInDecks") var card: LinkingObjects<Card>
}

class Card: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var cardInDecks = List<CardInDeck>()
}
```

Within a specific view, it's possible to see the information of a `CardInDeck` item. Part of that view is a list of all cards possible to choose as the card for this specific `CardInDeck` item.

Maybe there's a smarter way, but currently, to change the referenced card for the `CardInDeck` item, I remove the `CardInDeck` reference from the specific `Card` object and try to update it with the new `CardInDeck` item. But I'm facing the following issue:

**Object is already managed by another Realm. Use create instead to copy it into this Realm**

That's the code of how the view looks like:

```
struct CustomizeCardInDeckView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Card.self) var cards
    @ObservedRealmObject var cardInDeck: CardInDeck
    
    @State var selectedCard: Card?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                if let referencedCard = cardInDeck.card.first {
                    Section("Card") {
                        List(cards, selection: $selectedCard) { card in
                            HStack {
                                Text(card.name)
                                Spacer()
                                if referencedCard == card {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                let realm = try! Realm()
                                
                                let currentCard = realm.objects(Card.self).where { $0._id == referencedCard._id }.first!
                                let cardToUse = realm.objects(Card.self).where {$0._id == card._id }.first!
                                
                                try! realm.write {
                                    if let index = currentCard.cardInDecks.firstIndex(of: card) {
                                        currentCard.cardInDecks.remove(at: index)
                                    }
                                    
                                    cardToUse.cardInDecks.append(card)
                                }
                                
                                selectedCard = card
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what line is throwing the error. I suspect it's here`cardToUse.cardInDecks.append(card)` but please verify. cads (card) is managed by a Realm on a different thread than cardToUse so that could be the issue.